# Why does Vuetify Autocomplete not selecting the data being set?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I use Vuetify autocomplete as a reusable component to display a list of jobs in key/value pairs. In creating record, the component works fine but when editing where data should be filled in, the data has the value but not showing on the component.

JobDropdownSelector.vue: 
................................................................................................................................................

```
<template>
    <v-autocomplete
        v-model="job"
        label="Job Designation"
        item-value="id"
        item-text="name"
        return-object
        :items="jobs"
        @change="onChange"
    >
    </v-autocomplete>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    props: {
        selectedJob: {
            type: Object,
            default: null
        }
    },
    data() {
        return {
            jobs: [],
            job: null
        };
    },
    methods: {
        getDataFromApi() {
                axios.get("api/jobs")
                    .then(response => {
                        this.jobs = response.data.data;
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.log(error);
                        reject();
                    });
        },
        onChange(e) {
            this.job = e;
            this.$emit("onChange", e);
        }
    },
    watch: {
        selectedJob: {
            deep: true, 
            immediate: true,
            handler(newValue, oldValue) {
                this.job = newValue;
            }
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.getDataFromApi();
    }
    
};
</script>
```

EditForm.vue:
................................................................................................................................................

```
<template>
    <div>
    <JobDropdownSelector
                v-model="job"
                :selectedJob="job"
                @onChange="onChangeJob"
        >
        </JobDropdownSelector>
    </div>
</template>


<script>
import JobDropdownSelector from "../components/JobDropdownSelector";

export default {
    components: {
        JobDropdownSelector
    },
    data() {
        return {
            job: null
        };
    },
    methods: {
        onChangeJob(e) {
            this.job = e;
        },
        getInitialJob() {
            axios.get("api/jobs/22").then(response => {
                this.job = response.data.data;
            });
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.getInitialJob();
    }
};
</script>
```

[Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ueXJ.png)
[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sk7sA.png)

Comment: Got the same problem. have you figured it out yet? this is frustrated :(

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you overriding `job` twice: on the `onChangeJob` method and via v-model on `JobDropdownSelector`.

You can try use `input` event to update modek instead of emitting additional event.

**JobDropdownSelector.vue**

```js
methods: {
  onChange(e) {
    // You don't need set job because it's connected via v-model.
    // this.job = e; 
    this.$emit("input", e);
  }
}
```

This will cause that `job` in **EditForm.vue** should update automatically after dropdown change.

Comment: Still got the same result when editing a certain record. The autocomplete does not select the job data being loaded.